# ThreeJS .dae Not loading textures

Tags: three.js, collada

```
<library_images>
    <image id="ID9">
        <init_from>
            ./textures/Seats_Lvl2b_2k.jpg
        </init_from>
    </image>
```

In the default skinning example for Collada via ThreeJS website I see that this should hold my images and then the for loop would print them out however they do not show the textures from my .dae file and it results in my DAE file loading in the browser but no textures applied.

```
skin = collada.skins[ 0 ];
```

If I print out:

```
skin = collada.dae['images'];
```

The log shows:

[image]

Other warnings in the log are:

THREE.MeshPhongMaterial: 'diffuse' is not a property of this material.
11: ColladaLoader.js:3020 unhandled Sampler2D prop: instance_image
three.min.js:381 THREE.MeshPhongMaterial: 'diffuse' is not a property of this material.

All images are placed relative on the server.

Advice welcome

Comment: I took this further by loading converting the FBX to JSON and the supported tools however the images never load against the json file. I have now using the Dev branch of the threeJS for latest builds

Answer (score 0):

If you can share the COLLADA model you can get more specific advice, but without that I'd recommend converting to FBX or glTF and using FBXLoader or glTFLoader, respectively.